# MS SQL Server database bakcup

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, backup, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server2008 R2 and SQL Server2016.
I have Database of 500 GB.

My Question:

I have restored same database backup on both SQL server versions, but when I am going to take backup of that database on SQL server 2008 R2 backup size become 100  GB around but in SQL server 2016 it reached 350 GB arond.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Dhaval,

Sounds to me like Backup compression is not enabled on your 2016 Instance.

The following will guide you in checking and enabling said feature if desired: [view or configure the backup compression default server configuration option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-configure-the-backup-compression-default-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2016)